# How can I drop repeating values in a column while keeping the data for its rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe that has column of repeating values/indexes and I want to group it by the 'Name' column but without performing any aggregation to it. I've looked at the `Dataframe.groupby()` function but from what I've searched, you are kind of forced to perform an aggregation. I've also tried `Dataframe.set_index('Name')` and then do `Dataframe.sort_index(inplace = True)` but it for some reason it returns a `Nonetype` I feel like it's something obvious but I can't quite figure it out.

This is my dataframe now:

```
Name Data1 Data2
A    .1    1.1
A    .2    1.2
A    .3    1.3
B    .6    1.6
B    .7    1.7
B    .8    1.8
C    1.0   2.0
C    1.1   2.1
C    1.2   2.2
```

This is what I want:

```
Name Data1 Data2
A    .1    1.1
     .2    1.2
     .3    1.3
B    .6    1.6
     .7    1.7
     .8    1.8
C    1.0   2.0
     1.1   2.1
     1.2   2.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want replace duplicated values to empty strings use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].mask(df['Name'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)
  Name  Data1  Data2
0    A    0.1    1.1
1         0.2    1.2
2         0.3    1.3
3    B    0.6    1.6
4         0.7    1.7
5         0.8    1.8
6    C    1.0    2.0
7         1.1    2.1
8         1.2    2.2
```

In `MultiIndex` for first look it also working, but NOT, values are only in default view NOT displayed in first level(s) if duplicated:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Name','Data1'])
print (df1)
            Data2
Name Data1       
A    0.1      1.1
     0.2      1.2
     0.3      1.3
B    0.6      1.6
     0.7      1.7
     0.8      1.8
C    1.0      2.0
     1.1      2.1
     1.2      2.2
```

Check [docs, In [21]:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object), there is no omited data, only moved to `MultiIndex`:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df1)

            Data2
Name Data1       
A    0.1      1.1
A    0.2      1.2
A    0.3      1.3
B    0.6      1.6
B    0.7      1.7
B    0.8      1.8
C    1.0      2.0
C    1.1      2.1
C    1.2      2.2
```

Or if convert values of `MultiIndex` to list:

```
print (df1.index.tolist())
[('A', 0.1), ('A', 0.2), ('A', 0.3), 
 ('B', 0.6), ('B', 0.7), ('B', 0.8), 
 ('C', 1.0), ('C', 1.1), ('C', 1.2)]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all the options! I was looking for the first one where duplicates gets replaced with empty values.